# Detect class 'activeslide' change from one li to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am having a slide show which marks the slide that is active with the class `activeslide`
I want to detect each time when the class changes from one li to another.
I tried this:

```
$('#supersized li').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Then I want to know which slide is active... that is, is it slide-0 or slide-1 etc...
How can I do this with jQuery? I have pasted the list below:

```
<ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;">
<li class="slide-0 activeslide" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
<li class="slide-1" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
<li class="slide-2" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
<li class="slide-3 prevslide" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
</ul>
```

Comment: What is changing the class names?

Comment: I mean the 'activeslide' class changes from one li to another right...

Comment: are you using a plugin, and if so which one?

Comment: am using supersized plugin(http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .change() event triggers only when controls selection changes, as when selecting an <option> of a <select>

from jQuery [.change() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements.

if a class changes if because you changed it. you could use .trigger() (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to dispatch a user event from the funciton that changes classes and .bind() (http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to respond to it